# Class Method in Python not seeing a defined variable

Tags: python, class, class-method

I'm using a Python Class for the first time, and even though I've defined a variable in "**init**", the classmethod still is giving me an error saying I have not defined it, appreciate any advice.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as si
import pandas as pd

from math import sqrt, exp, log, pi

class Option:
    def __init__ (self, S, K, T, r, price, option):
        self.S = S
        self.K = K
        self.T = T
        self.r = r
        self.price = price
        self.option = option
        self.sigma = self.bs_implied_vol()

    @classmethod
    def bs_price (self, sigma):    
        d1 = (np.log(S / K) + (r + 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * T) / (sigma * np.sqrt(T))
        d2 = (np.log(S / K) + (r - 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * T) / (sigma * np.sqrt(T))
        if option == 'call':
            result = (S * si.norm.cdf(d1, 0.0, 1.0) - K * np.exp(-r * T) * si.norm.cdf(d2, 0.0, 1.0))
        if option == 'put':
            result = (K * np.exp(-r * T) * si.norm.cdf(-d2, 0.0, 1.0) - S * si.norm.cdf(-d1, 0.0, 1.0))        
        return result

    @classmethod
    def bs_implied_vol (self):
        vol = 0.5
        epsilon = 1.0  
        abstol = 1e-4  
        i = 0   
        max_iter = 1e3  
        while epsilon > abstol:
            if i > max_iter:
                break
            i = i + 1
            orig = vol
            function_value = self.bs_price(vol) - price
            vega = S * si.norm.pdf(d1) * sqrt(T)
            vol = -function_value/vega + vol
            epsilon = abs(function_value)
        return vol

option = Option (99.4,99.5,0.2,0.001,0.09683,'call')
```

The error I'm getting is:

> NameError: name 'S' is not defined

Comment: A couple of problems. First, if you make something a `classmethod` then its passed the class object `Option` when called, not an instance of the class, so no instance variables are available. Second, inside a class or instance method, you still have to use the `cls` or `self` variable to get at the data. Remove `@classmethod` and reference via `self.S` and etc and you are good  to go.

Comment: Here is the standard tutorial on classes https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html